# sharepoint 2013: document set metadata updated; documents metadata not updated

Tags: document-set, metadata

A document set with X column is created. X column is set to be shared to documents inside the document set.
I upload documents in the document set; I modify the X column of the document set.
Documents are not updated for the X column. I'm sure i have already seen the X column updated on documents in other projects in the past.
Has anybody an idea on this issue?

Comment: How many documents did you upload into the document set?

Comment: Document set to item columns value sync is managed thru a timer job. Have you already checked such job is still running??

Comment: Hi. My document sets had 2 or 3 documents. It seems to me I checked the timer job, and ran it to be sure it was not faulty.